# Why did Torchwood have the ghost shift lever?

Tags: doctor-who, cybermen

The "ghosts" were the Cybermen trying to instantiate themselves in the world, but where did Torchwood get the lever that controlled the ghost shifts? Why were they running the shifts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As to "why" they were running the shifts, the answer is [in the show](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/28-12.htm). They were trying to create a disruption at a known point of dimensional instability (e.g. where the [Void Ship](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Void_Ship) emerged) in order to harness the energy they detected.

> **DOCTOR:** *So, you find the breach, probe it, the sphere comes through six hundred feet above London, bam. It leaves a hole in the
>   fabric of reality. And that hole, you think, oh, shall we leave it
>   alone? Shall we back off? Shall we play it safe? Nah, you think let's
>   make it bigger!*
>
> **YVONNE:** ***It's a massive source of energy.*** If we can harness that power, we need never depend on the Middle East again. Britain
>   will become truly independent. Look, you can see for yourself. Next
>   Ghost Shift's in two minutes.

As to "where" they got the lever, there's no canon explantion but it's quire reasonable to presume that they built it themselves out of the various components they've salvaged from the numerous alien invasions that have happened over the years.

Answer (score 0):

Torchwood is a research organization. They detected an invisible breach in the universe (through which the *Void Ship* came) which was the source of *Ghost Energy* and build their building around it.

Torchwood then tried to open that breach to harness that ghost energy. The attempt resulted in *Ghost Shifts*.

Comment: They are not a research organization.

Comment: @Simon But, they do research...

Comment: Nope. They were created by Queen Victoria to fight supernatural and alien incursions in the UK (named after the Torchwood incident). Later on they changed their M.O. to re-establish the UK as the world leader.

Comment: @Simon Fighting aliens and supernaturals requires lots of research...

Comment: The US military do lots of research and development. You wouldn't call them a research organisation. If you would like to know more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torchwood_Institute

Comment: They were charged with defending the UK from hostile aliens. To mount an effective defense, they need all the alien tech they can get their hands on. So, they collect what they can. But, they have to figure out how it works so they can make use of it. Hence the research aspect of their operation. Yvonne Hartman more or less spells it out to the Doctor within a minute or so of their first meeting.